# Almost completing the argument: $p: L \to L$ a projector, then $im~ p \oplus \ker p = L$.

Tags: linear-algebra

I had to show that if $p: L \to L$ is a projector, then $im ~p \oplus \ker p = L$.
This was easy. Now I have to show that the matrix of $p$ is divided on four blocks where one of them is $r$ dimensional (The dimension of image of p) and the others are just composed by zeros.

(Sorry, I don't know ho to insert matrix here.)

What I have trying is:
Choose some basis for $\ker p$. Then complete it until obtain one basis for $L$.  Now the argument that I dont know is, how can I assure that this complement of basis that I choosed that is $r-$dimensional is such that we have the matrix of $p$ such as searched.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is either a basic theorem about direct sums (or an alternative *definition* of a direct sum) that if $V=U \oplus W$, $\alpha$ is a basis for $U$ and $\beta$ is a basis for $W$, then $\alpha \cup \beta$ (a disjoint union) is a basis for $V$.

So you're close. Pick a basis for the image, say $\alpha = \{u_1,\dots,u_r \}$. Then (don't try to "complete" the basis $\alpha$ instead) pick a basis for the kernel, say $\beta = \{ w_1, \dots, w_m \}$ (where $m+r=\dim(L)$). Since you have bases for subspaces which direct sum to $L$, you have that $\gamma = \alpha \cup \beta = \{u_1,\dots,u_r,w_1,\dots,w_m\}$ is a basis for $L$.

The matrix of $p$ relative to this basis will have an $r \times r$ identity block (since $p(u_i)=u_i$ because $u_i$ is in the image of the projection where the projection acts as an idempotent) and then an $m \times m$ block of zeros (since $p(w_i)=0$ because $w_i$'s are in the kernel of $p$). Exactly what you want.

Comment: excelente! I did it! Thanks a lot!